# beautifulsoupを用いて、規則性のある20行24列の競馬のデータ表をCSVに書き込みたい

Tags: python, array, csv, python2, beautifulsoup

## 前提・実現したいこと

お世話になります、python初心者ですpython2.7,beautifulsoupを用いて、競馬データをスクレイピングしておりますが、どうにも困っております。 
１行だけはprintすることが出来るのですが、２０行をスクレイピングするスクリプトと、併せて、CSVに出力させるスクリプトが分かりません。

## 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

csvに保存が出来ないこと

２０行をまとめてスクレイピングすることが出来ないこと

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-


import urllib2
import codecs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = codecs.open('horse.csv', 'w', 'utf-8')
f.write('race_date,kaisai,weather,race_number,race_name,tousuu,frame_number,horse_number,single_win_ratio,popularity,horse_arrival,horse_name,weight,distance,baba, race_time,difference,horse_pass,pace,nobori,horse_weight,win_horse,prize_money'+ u"\n")

tpl_url='http://db.netkeiba.com/?pid=jockey_detail&id=00663&page={0}'

for i in xrange(1, 5):
    url=tpl_url.format( i )
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read(),"lxml")
    tr_arr = soup.find('div', {'id':'contents_liquid'}).findAll('tbody')  

    for tr in tr_arr:

    #日付#race_date
        lrg1= tr.findAll('td')[0].string
        #開催#kaisai
        lrg2= tr.findAll('td')[1].string
        #天気#weather
        lrg3= tr.findAll('td')[2].string
        #第○ﾚｰｽ#race_number
        lrg4= tr.findAll('td')[3].string
        #ﾚｰｽ名#race_name
        lrg5= tr.findAll('td')[4].string
        #映像（この部分、削除したいです）
        lrg6= tr.findAll('td')[5].string
        #頭数#tousuu
        lrg7= tr.findAll('td')[6].string
        #枠番#frame_number
        lrg8= tr.findAll('td')[7].string
        #馬番#horse_number
        lrg9= tr.findAll('td')[8].string
        #単勝#single_win_racio
        lrg10= tr.findAll('td')[9].string
        #人気#popularity
        lrg11= tr.findAll('td')[10].string
        #着順#horse_arrival
        lrg12= tr.findAll('td')[11].string
        #馬名#horse_name
        lrg13= tr.findAll('td',{'class':'txt_l'}) [1]
        #斤量#weight
        lrg14= tr.findAll('td')[13].string
        #距離#distance
        lrg15= tr.findAll('td')[14].string
        #馬場#baba
        lrg16= tr.findAll('td')[15].string
        #タイム#race_time
        lrg17= tr.findAll('td')[16].string
        #着差#difference
        lrg18= tr.findAll('td')[17].string
        #通過#horse_pass
        lrg19= tr.findAll('td')[18].string
        #ペース#pace
        lrg20= tr.findAll('td')[19].string
        #上り#nobori
        lrg21= tr.findAll('td')[20].string
        #馬体重#horse_weight
        lrg22= tr.findAll('td')[21].string
        #勝ち馬#win_horse
        lrg23= tr.findAll('td',{'class':'txt_l'}) [2]
        #賞金#prize_money
        lrg24= tr.findAll('td')[23].string

        print lrg1,lrg2,lrg3,lrg4,lrg5,lrg6,lrg7,lrg8,lrg9,lrg10,\
                  lrg11,lrg12,lrg13.a.string,lrg14,lrg15,lrg16,lrg17,\
                  lrg18,lrg19,lrg20,lrg21,lrg22,lrg23.a.string,lrg24


        f.close()
```

## 試したこと

forなどで、ループさせてみましたが、スキル不足でうまくいきませんでした。

## 補足情報(言語/FW/ツール等のバージョンなど)

python2.7

findAllを多用して、力ずくで作ったプログラムでございます。 
先輩の皆様方、御教示よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: マルチポスト: https://teratail.com/questions/43942

Answer (score 2):

テーブルには２０行があるのに、１行しか取得できないの原因は

```
soup.find('div', {'id':'contents_liquid'}).findAll('tbody')
```

`tbody` は一つしかないので、for ループが１回だけ走らせしました。`tbody` から各 `tr` を取り出す必要があります。すなわち

```
soup.find('div', {'id':'contents_liquid'}).find('tbody').findAll('tr')
```

なお、`tr.findAll('td')[0].string` は `NavigableString` タイプのオブジェクトを取り出すことです。その後 CSV に書き込むから、`tr.findAll('td')[0].text` で文字列を取得すべきです。

Python で csv の利用するのは、[こちら](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)ご参考ください。また、CSV に Unicode を書くため、各 unicode 文字列を `.encode('utf-8')` すれば結構です。なお、`with` 文を使用して、自ら `.close()` しないほうが良いと思います。

コードを修正してみました

```
import urllib2
import codecs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

# with 文を使い、f.close() を取り除きました
with open('horse.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['race_date', 'kaisai', 'weather', # ...
                    ])

    tpl_url='http://db.netkeiba.com/?pid=jockey_detail&id=00663&page={0}'

    for i in xrange(1, 5):
        url=tpl_url.format( i )
        soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read(),"lxml")
        tr_arr = soup.find('div', {'id':'contents_liquid'}).find('tbody').findAll('tr')

        for tr in tr_arr:
            tds = tr.findAll('td')

            lrg = []
            for index, td in enumerate(tr.findAll('td')):
                # ループの改善について：一部の td は特別処理されて
                if index == 12:
                    lrg.append(tr.findAll('td', {'class':'txt_l'})[1].text)
                elif index == 22:
                    lrg.append(tr.findAll('td', {'class':'txt_l'})[2].text)
                else:
                    # ほかの普通の td はそのままリストに入れる
                    lrg.append(td.text)

            writer.writerow([s.strip().encode('utf-8') for s in lrg])
```

Answer (score 1):

`f.close()`  した時点で続きを書き込めなくなり、2行目以降が出力されないのでしょう。
`f.close()` を削除してください。